# Need advice concerning the restoration of an sql 2005 Database

Tags: sql, database-restore, database-backups

Our goal is to restore a test environment from our live environment, so basically we
would like to simply backup our current live databases, and just restore them
in our test server.

However... we do not have enough room to move the backups, one of our databases 
is 50 GB, and we only have around 20 GB free(the backup is 40 GB uncompressed).
We were thinking of dropping that database to make room for the backup, but I'm assuming that when it restores it, it will run our space.

I am also thinking that we could just Detach/Attach the database file, but I am assuming that
this would mean that we have to take our live database down(which we don't want to do).

Another option is to restore from a network drive, so just set the restore to \severname\X$\RestoreFolder
But are there any things that I should be aware of if we do this?

I would like to thank everyone for your suggestions in advance.

Comment: Can you just - cough - go to a shop and get some space? 50gb is tiny. It was tiny when you wrote the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the database is 50 GB, is that just the MDF file? Or is does the LDF file make up a large portion of the 50 GB? Do you need all the log information on a test machine?

To be honest, I'd be tempted to buy a new hard drive and put it in the test server. Even the cheapest one you can find should have more than enough space for several test copies of the database.

Comment: If you've got more data than you have space, then you're stuck. Do you need all the data? Can you restore it somewhere else and delete most of the data and then shrink the database and back it up again?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your hardware. Even a development/test machine should have enough space to backup/restore the catalogs you're working with.

Comment: From what I was told, we are unable to add more space to the server. The server is actually a VM, from what I've been informed we are unable to add more space to that machine.

Comment: It's entirely possible to add more space to any type of VM that I've ever seen. This sounds more like an office politics problem than a real issue. If you can't allocate more space to the machine, then you can't restore the database. You might see if there's anything you can clear off the machine, but ultimately, you're probably going to have to push the issue with your server admin until they take care of it.